# JQuery: Push Effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using the JQuery slideDown/slideUp effect and am not accomplishing what I want.

Essentially, I want to create an action where I "push" a div off the top of the browser window.

Something similar to the [following push effect example.](http://aaronweyenberg.com/demos/voteflipper/demo.html)

How can I do this with JQuery?

The problem with just using slideDown/slideUp is that the other DIV just overlaps the div I'm hiding. But instead, I want to PUSH the div I don't want visible off the top of the browser window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make two divs, one inside the other. Using CSS, define a height for the outer one and set `overflow: hidden`. This means that if the inner div's content is too long, it will be invisible.

```
 ____ _____ ____
|    | ooo |    |   <-- this is the outer div
|____|_____|____|
     | xxx |       ooo -> visible
     |_____|       xxx -> invisible

        ^-- this is the inner div
```

Whatever you want to slide goes inside the inner div. Now all you need to do is move the inner div upwards:

```
      _____
     | ooo |
 ____|_____|____
|    | xxx |    |     now, ooo -> invisible
|____|_____|____|          xxx -> visible
```

This  can be done using jQuery's [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) function.

```
$('#innerDiv').animate({
    top: -50px
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand you well, but you could just animate it, like

```
var pos = $('#myDIV').position();
$('#myDIV').css({
   position:   'absolute',
   left:       pos.left,
   top:        pos.top,       
}).animate({
   top:        '-=400'
},{
   duration:   2000,
   complete:   function(){
      $(this).remove();
   }
});
```

that should move your div out of view and remove it afterwards. If it's not what you want
you can hopefully adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

i think, this is what u are looking for
http://jsfiddle.net/JuW3B/2/